# How to automatically change bearer token in python code

Tags: python, web-scraping, curl, python-requests, bearer-token

I am scraping a site in an hourly basis through post requests but everyday the authorisation bearer token changes and I have to copy paste new token from the site to my headers dict. How can I automate this so that I don’t have to copy paste this new token everyday. Is there any way so that I can get the token through site link and save it as a variable so that I can pass through the header dict. Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you do a plain request to the site and extract the token from the HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NachoR The token is not present in the HTML. It is present in the network section of the site.